# Django filter startswith works on locally but not on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-views, heroku-postgres

When I run the following locally using SQLite it works fine and returns a list of all items starting with "a", but when run on heroku (using Postres) it returns an empty set.

`views.py`

```
data = Items.objects.filter(item__startswith="a").values_list('item',flat=True)
print(data)
```

`models.py`

```
class Items(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: instead of ```.values_list()``` try ```.only()```

Comment: This is one of the _many_ reasons not to use different databases in development and production. SQLite and PostgreSQL are _different products_; you can't just drop one in for the other and expect it to work exactly the same. I _strongly_ urge you to use PostgreSQL in development if you are going to use it in production.

Comment: I switched local development to Postgres and it seems to be a problem with `filter(item__startswith="a")`, if I switch this to `all()` it returns the entire list. Is there an alternative way to filter on startswith?

Comment: It seems like `startswith` is case insensitive on SQLite, but case sensitive with Postgres. `filter(item_istartswith="a")` works on Postgres. Thanks